# Caml Query Simple IDs

Tags: sharepoint, caml

My Code for client sharepoint 2013 with JS
doesnt work :(

here the snippet:

```
    var query ='<view><query><where><in><fieldRef Name="Id"><values>';

    for (var i in items) {
        query += '<value Type="Counter">' + items[i].id + '</value>';
     }
    query += "</values></fieldref></in></where></query></view>";
```

my question is , what is wrong here ;) I dont know, because when i set the query, then become all items from the list and  not only with this ids.

thx Andi;)

Comment: At least this is not a valid XML: `fieldRef` upper case 'R', vs. `fieldref` lower case 'r'.

Comment: Plus "doesn't work" is not really an error message or problem statement. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In cases where a CAML query is malformed, SharePoint will generally give you the default view of the list instead of respecting your query. Sounds like that's what's happening here. If you can clean up your CAML query to meet SharePoint's expectations, it should work the way you want.

First, CAML is case-sensitive. Each tag name in your CAML should begin with a capital letter. Additionally, the built in ID field is queried with all caps `"ID"` instead of with `"Id"`.

Another thing to note is that the FieldRef element should be a self-closing tag (`<FieldRef />` instead of `<FieldRef></FieldRef>`).

Finally, be aware that if you have more than 500 values in your range, the `<Where><In>` operation will fail, as mentioned in [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/80212/38950). If you don't expect your query to contain a range of 500 values, you can disregard that limitation.

After updating your code to account for the above, it will probably look something like this:

```
var query = '<View><Query><Where>';
if(items.length < 500){
    query += '<In><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Values>';
    for (var i in items) {
        query += '<Value Type="Counter">' + items[i].id + '</Value>';
     }
    query += '</Values></In>';
}else{
    var orCounter = 0;
    for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++){
        if(i % 500 == 0){
            if(orCounter > 0){
                query += '</Values></In>'
            }
            if(i+501 < items.length){
               query += '<Or>';
               orCounter++;
            }
            query += '<In><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Values>';
        }
        query += '<Value Type="Counter">' + items[i].id + '</Value>';
    }
    query += '</Values></In>';
    for(var j = 0; j < orCounter; j++){
        query+="</Or>";
    }
}
query += '</Where></Query></View>';
```

However, we'd need to see how the `query` text is being used to determine if there are other issues that might be impacting the behavior of the query.